# Magento 2.4. Hide Shipping & Handling in Order Confirmation E-Mail

Tags: order-confirmation, order-confirmation-email

I'm having a problem with my order confirmation e-mail. Yesterday it didn't show a position for shipping and handling, but now it does.
As a wholesale it's not possible for us to calculate shipping and handling till the order is picked and finished.
Is there any way to hide shipping & handling again?
Thanks a lot for your answers!
[this is the e-mail without shipping & handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kZnD.jpg)
[image: this is the e-mail with shipping & handling (its in german and says Versand & Bearbeitung]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to edit the order confirmation e-mail template.

Go to Marketing > Email Templates > Select the Order Confirmation Email Template.

There you find the element you want to remove. Just remove it, then save the template.

Please check this article if you may
https://amasty.com/blog/create-edit-magento-2-email-templates/

[image]